# How do I preserve flags/width in a printf-formatted NSString used as a key for NSLocalizedString?

Tags: cocoa, cappuccino, localizable.strings

I use `genstrings` to generate `.strings` files from source code files in my project. Though the project is technically a [Cappuccino](http://cappuccino.org/) app, this question should apply equally to any project that uses `.strings` files.

I have a format string that I'd like to be localized: `@"%d:%02d %@"`. It is for displaying time values. If this were a OSX/iOS app, I'd use the built-in datetime formatting, but since it's Cappuccino I have to roll my own. When I run `genstrings` it produces this value for that key: `"%1$d:%2$d %3$@"`.

This is as it appears in the `Localizable.strings` file:

```
/* ShortLocalTimeFormat */
"%d:%02d %@" = "%1$d:%2$d %3$@";
```

by running this command: `genstrings -o Resources/en.lproj -s CPLocalizedString *.j */*.j`

Again, ignore that I'm using `CPLocalizedString` instead of `NSLocalizedStrings` and `*.j` instead of `*.m`, as these values are appropriate for Cappuccino. Notice that the `02` in `%02d` is discarded in the resulting format string. If I run it again with the `-noPositionalParameters` option, it just leaves the string as is: `genstrings -o Resources/en.lproj -noPositionalParameters -s CPLocalizedString *.j */*.j`.

```
/* ShortLocalTimeFormat */
"%d:%02d %@" = "%d:%02d %@";
```

Is this a bug in `genstrings`, or is it not possible to use flags/width in format strings while keeping positional parameters?

Answer (score 0):

If this were an Objective-C project, I would shorten the format strings to `"%1$@ %2$@"` and use an `NSDateFormatter` to generate the time string. If the class is not available, I would generate the intermediate time string myself and use the string as a parameter for the localized format string rather than passing hours/minutes to the localized format string directly.

Comment: I suppose the `HH:MM` part of a time string doesn't really change between locales... or, if it does, I doubt I'll be supporting one of those locales. No words of wisdom on `genstrings`?

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed this bug as well; it's not just you. However, it seems to occur only for `%d` specifiers — I'm using `%02d` and it turns into `%1$d`, but `%.02f` turns into `%1$.02f`.

I've filed [a bug](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=994402).